# Spring Transaction configuration programmatically with Spring 4.3.4 version

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

We are currently migrating from xml configuration to complete annotation with java configuration based Spring application. With the annotation approach **@Transactional** we can achieve but the we need to write for each and every method.

**In XML we configured (OLD).**

```
<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
                <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
                <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
                <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="is*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly</prop>
                <!--<prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**transactionManager** is **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager**

```
<bean id="xxxxSVC" parent="txProxyTemplate">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="XXX.XXX.XXX.SVCImpl">
                <property name="xxxxDao" ref="xxxDao"></property>

            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**txProxyTemplate** is parent class of each service class.

So, please suggest how to configure similar code in java configuration. Thanks for your valuable time spent and support us.

**@Barath Comment**

**Bean**

```
@Bean
    public TransactionProxyFactoryBean setTransactionProperties() throws IOException {
        TransactionProxyFactoryBean transactionProxyFactoryBean = new TransactionProxyFactoryBean();
        transactionProxyFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager(sessionFactory()));
        Properties transactionAttributesProps = new Properties();
        transactionAttributesProps.setProperty("delete*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        transactionAttributesProps.setProperty("update*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        transactionAttributesProps.setProperty("save*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        transactionAttributesProps.setProperty("get*", "PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly");
        transactionAttributesProps.setProperty("is*", "PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly");
        transactionProxyFactoryBean.setTransactionAttributes(transactionAttributesProps);

        transactionProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return transactionProxyFactoryBean;
    }
```

How to configure with each service implementation class, we can use it for single as a service layer may contain N classes. There is a method setTarget(Object target). Now how can we configure all the N classes. Please sugggest how can we configure.

Comment: you can simply make use of @Bean to convert  xml to java configuration of respective classes with properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample configuration for this case :

```
    @Bean
    public TransactionProxyFactoryBean txProxyTemplate(){

        TransactionProxyFactoryBean txFactory=new TransactionProxyFactoryBean();
        txFactory.setTransactionManager(new JpaTransactionManager()); // any transcation manager 
        txFactory.setTransactionAttributes(properties());
        return txFactory;

    }

    @Bean 
    Properties properties(){
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        properties.put("delete*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        //set al lthe properties
        return  properties;
    }


    @Bean
    public TransactionProxyFactoryBean  xxxxSVC(TransactionProxyFactoryBean txFactory){
        txFactory.setTarget(testEntity());
        return txFactory;
    }

    @Bean 
    TestEntity  testEntity(){
        return new TestEntity();
    }
```

Comment: This is complex I understand. when you are migrating  from xml to java configuration it is better you go ahead with @Transcational itself

Comment: @Bean 
    TestEntity  testEntity(){
        return new TestEntity();
    }

Comment: its just a sample. you can set target as per your configuration

Comment: Here is for each class we can configure but how can we configure for all service layer classes without using @Transactional.

Comment: how about applying aspects using AOP ? let me search for any example and get back to you

Comment: https://iamgodsom.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/wrox-professional-java-development-with-the-spring-framework.pdf     page no . 230 to 231 to set multiple beanNames